# How to authenticate user manually in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have two tables 'user' and 'role'.I want to create a login api (e.g '/login') which will take username and password as a json data. I want to check if given credential is a valid credential and if it is,then I want to set the user as authenticated user so that he/she may have the protected resources. I am new to spring boot framework and I don't know how to do so.I have read the offical documentation but cannot find any resources.Could someone help me on this?

Comment: use spring-security role based authorization. [this link](http://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration) might help you to some extent

Comment: @harshavmb thank you very much.Your link was very much helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have number of choices to implement such authentication in Spring.

**Case 1:-** If you are building REST services then you can implement security in following ways:

*i)*  - you can use Basic-Authentication to authenticate your user.

*ii)* - you can use OAuth2 to authenticate and authorize your user.

**Case 2:** If you are building web application

*i)*  - you can use auth token (in case of Single page application SPA)

*ii)* - you can use session based authentication (traditional login form and all)

I Guess you are in beginner mode so i will recommend you to firstly understand the control flow user authentication in web app via login form. So Let's go through some code.

I'm assuming that you have set a basic spring project and now you are implementing security.

USER - Hibernate entity for your user table;
ROLE - Hibernate entity for your role table

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private CustomAuthProvider customAuthProvider;
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // everyone is allowed tp view login page
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().and();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("custom_base_path" + "**").authenticated().and().
    formLogin().loginPage("/loginForm).loginProcessingUrl("/loginUser")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("custom_base_path+ "home", true);

@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);
}


//CustomAuthProvider
@Component
public class CustomAuthentiationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String userid = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    Authentication auth = null;
    try {
 //write your custom logic to match username, password
boolean userExists = your_method_that_checks_username_and_password
        if(userExists ){
            List<Role> roleList= roleDao.getRoleList(userid);
            if (roleList == null || roleList.isEmpty()) {
                throw new NoRoleAssignedException("No roles is assigned to "+userid);
            }
            auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userid, password,getGrantedAuthorities(roleList));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("error", e);
    }
    return auth;

}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}

public List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<Role> roleList) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    for (Role role : roleList) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName());
    }
    return authorities;
}
}
```

**NOTE:** *Please consider these codes to understand the logic of authentication. don't consider as perfect code(Not for production env.). You can ping me anytime i'll suggest you more about that.*