# Spring Starter Security not authenticating

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

When I add a User with "ROLE_USER" permissions, I am unable to authenticate. 401s are returned consistently when attempting to authenticate with username: "username" and password: "password".

I can see in the JSON that's output that the BCryptPasswordEncoder is encoding passwords as it should be, but regardless of whether I use the original password or encoded version, I'm still unable to authenticate.

I've been working on this for a couple of days to no avail. Is there anything I'm missing?

Code is below --

DatabaseLoader:

```
User user = new User("first", "last", "username", "password", "email", "phone", new String[] {"ROLE_USER"});
userRepository.save(user);
```

DetailsService:

```
@Component
public class DetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository users;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userUsername) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = users.findByUsername(userUsername);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(userUsername + " was not found");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getUserPassword(),
                AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(user.getUserRoles())
        );
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    DetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(User.PASSWORD_ENCODER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    public static final PasswordEncoder PASSWORD_ENCODER = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    private long userId;
    private String userFirstName;
    private String userLastName;
    private String username;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String userPassword;
    private String userPhone;
    private String userEmail;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String[] userRoles;

    public User() {}

    public User(String userFirstName, String userLastName, String username, String userPassword, String userPhone, String userEmail, String[] userRoles) {
        this.userFirstName = userFirstName;
        this.userLastName = userLastName;
        this.username = username;
        setUserPassword(userPassword);
        this.userPhone = userPhone;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column
    public String getUserFirstName() {
        return userFirstName;
    }

    public void setUserFirstName(String userFirstName) {
        this.userFirstName = userFirstName;
    }

    @Column
    public String getUserLastName() {
        return userLastName;
    }

    public void setUserLastName(String userLastName) {
        this.userLastName = userLastName;
    }

    @Column
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column
    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = PASSWORD_ENCODER.encode(userPassword);
    }

    @Column
    public String getUserPhone() {
        return userPhone;
    }

    public void setUserPhone(String userPhone) {
        this.userPhone = userPhone;
    }

    @Column
    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }

    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    @Column
    public String[] getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(String[] userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear about problem. But i guess you are stuck in user authentication with spring starter security.
 You should check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511357/how-to-authenticate-user-manually-in-spring-boot/44513398#44513398)

Comment: You’re right, question wasn’t specific enough. It’s more passwordencoder related - will rephrase and ask a new question. Thanks!

Comment: It did help me to learn more about Spring Starter Security. My issue was specifically down to the password encoder - the encoded password would never match up. I dropped that totally and am now using plain text passwords stored in a String. Will look further into password encryption when it is needed. Thanks!